# Not able to deploy NodeJS App in Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I created a NodeJS app using JetBrain Webstrom and now i would like to deploy it to heroku.

[This image contains my app directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqeRg.jpg)

Should I remove node_modules to deploy the app ? 
or should i add any "engine" section under package.json ? 
What should I do to get my app deployed properly in heroku.

My app's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "form",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.2",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Log while Pushing the App:

```
C:\Users\Adhik\formgp>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 585 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to serene-bayou-91098.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/serene-bayou-91098.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/serene-bayou-91098.git'
```

Comment: Did you go to the URL mentioned in the error message? The one that has a section called "Setting a buildpack on an application"?

Comment: Yup tried it. 
I modified my heroku app by using this command
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
Still I was not able to deploy.

Comment: Does the message change after setting a buildpack?

Comment: Yup It changes to this.-----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
remote:
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your package.json:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "whatever_version_you_want"
  }
```

You shouldn't need to install/remove node_modules, Heroku should do that for you.

Comment: `node_modules` should probably be in the `.gitignore`, though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like engines are missing in your package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.7.0",
    "npm": "3.10.3"
  }
```

Also deploying a Procfile can be helpful:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

Are you sure you are deploying the entire folder? Check your logs:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
```